# How can I check whether multiple variables are equal to the same value?

Tags: c++

How do I compare multiple items? For example, I wish to check if all the variables A, B, and C are equal to the char 'X' or all three are equal to 'O'. (If 2 of them are X and one is O it should return false.)

I tried:

```
if (A, B, C == 'X' || A, B, C == 'O') 
  {
    //Do whatever
  }
```

but it didn't work. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: BTW, wouldn't you be better off with an array instead of A, B, C variables? Just asking

Comment: I am using a variable. By A, B,C I mean: myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2].

Comment: It seems that there is no other way than to do this other than the answer below or just simply testing them one by one. Thanks anway.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if((A == 'X' || A == 'O') && A == B && B == C)
{
    // Do whatever
}
```

Comment: why complicate a simple thing?

Comment: @Kos: why my is complicated and why is it a simple thing?

Comment: I agree with @Kos - this should be written as the expanded form to make it easier for other programmers to understand exactly what you're doing. Compilers optimize these boolean conditions better than we can, anyway.

Comment: No sorry. I need an expression that will return true if A, B and C all equal O or X. If one is O and another is X it should return false. Il change my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Well, testing it simply one-by-one would make it easier to read. But you can just as well write a comment, so... Never mind :)

Comment: @DavidTitarenco: I never thought of optimization when writing this. for me this is easier

Comment: I have a habit of avoiding clever tricks when programming. Clever tricks is what made my most awesome bugs :D.

Comment: @sudsiv, this answer accomplishes what you want to do.

Comment: @Kos: I think he was referring to BasileStarynkevitch's comment and not the answer

Comment: @Kos I find this code _much_ clearer than what the OP was trying to write. There are no "tricks" here; just basic logic.

Answer (score 15):

Just for variety:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
bool allequal(const T &t, const U &u) {
    return t == u;
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Others>
bool allequal(const T &t, const U &u, Others const &... args) {
    return (t == u) && allequal(u, args...);
}

if (allequal(a,b,c,'X') || allequal(a,b,c,'O')) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks alot! You just gave me the idea of making a function to achieve this!

Answer (score 0):

Just seperate them and test them one by one:

```
if (A == 'O' && B == 'O' && C == 'O' || A == 'X' && B == 'X' && C == 'X')
    // etc
```

Comment: You need to add `()` there or it will basically go one by one and not your intended of testing two groups separately and `or`ing them.

Comment: @Dani I believe you, but will you explain why? The operators in order of descending precedence are `==` then `&&` then `||`, right? Doesn't that mean that all the `==` are done first, then the `&&`, then the `||`? And isn't that correct?

Comment: nope, `&&` and `||` have same precedence, so first all the `==` will happen, then 2 `&&` then `||` and then the last `&&`

Comment: @Dani: that's not true, `&&` and `||` do not have equal precedence. `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.