# C++ - if statement simplification

Tags: c++, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check whether multiple variables are equal to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196796/how-can-i-check-whether-multiple-variables-are-equal-to-the-same-value)

Is there a way to write this:

```
    if ((var1==var2) && (var2==var3) && (var3==var4) ...)
```

into something like this

```
    if (var1==var2==var3==var4 ...)
```

?

Comment: Short answer: yes, but is not a wise idea

Comment: @Nik Bougalis: Yes, "there is a way to write that thing into something like that other thing"

Comment: @K-ballo: Such that it maintains the same semantics? Unlikely.

Comment: When working with boolean types you could do something like this:
    `if (!((int)(v1+v2+v3) % 3)) {
       cout << "all are equal" << endl;
    }`

Answer (score 5):

In C++11, you could write a set of functions like this:

```
template<typename T>
bool all_equal(T const &)
{
    return true;
}

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
bool all_equal(T const & a, U const & b, Args const&... c)
{
    return a==b && all_equal(b,c...);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << all_equal(1,2,3) << '\n';
    std::cout << all_equal(1,1,1) << '\n';
}
```

Edit: I guess Steve Jessop had this same idea on the linked duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198279/440119)

Comment: If each `all_equal` can be inlined... this is one cool use of variadic templates.

Answer (score 1):

Not in a way that's clearer than that, no. You can insert the values in a `set` for example and check the if `size == 1`, but what you have now is the way to go.

Comment: Whilst your answer of "no" is correct, your alternative would be a poor implementation as it would be O(N log N) to insert all the elements into a set, and wouldn't break immediately when it found a non-equal case.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, no.

If you have a collection, rather than just sporadic variables, it is possible to apply algorithms to check if they are all equal, which are `O(N)` if they are all indeed equal (as your long statement is) and will break immediately when it finds one that is not.