# Logic Error in TicTacToe game

Tags: c++, logic

here's a simple logic error I can't quite wrap my head around:

Why does the following statement always equate to true?

```
if ( (grid[i][0] && grid[i][1] && grid[i][2]) == ('X' || 'x') ) return true;
```

It works flawlessly for

```
if ( (grid[i][0] && grid[i][1] && grid[i][2]) == ('X') return true;
```

Comment: Neither of those will do what you want.  The result of && and || is type bool, so the == has arguments of type bool.

Comment: _"It works flawlessly for ..."_ Certainly not.

Comment: this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196796/how-can-i-check-whether-multiple-variables-are-equal-to-the-same-value

Comment: try `if ((grid[i][0] == 'X' && grid[i][1] == 'X' && grid[i][2] == 'X') 
|| (grid[i][0] == 'x' && grid[i][1] == 'x' && grid[i][2] == 'x'))` instead

Comment: You could also try this `if((grid[i][0] == 'X' || grid[i][0] == 'x') && grid[i][0] == grid[i][1] && grid[i][1] == grid[i][2])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the expressions

```
'X' || 'x'
```

and

```
grid[i][0] && grid[i][1] && grid[i][2]
```

use the `||` and `&&` operators between non-zero integer-typed values (because `char` is an integer type) and so they both evaluate to `true`.

To translate into C++ (or almost any other somewhat similar language, for that matter) that you want characters `x`, `y` and `z` to be equal to either of the characters `c` and `C`, you must compute

```
(x == c || x == C) && (y == c || y == C) && (z == c || z == C)
```

so apply that to your problem.

More importantly though, learn about boolean operators and programming in general before you try to tackle C++.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

create a function to check a character of being x:

```
bool isX(char c)
{
  return c == 'X' || c == 'x';
}
```

and the you can write:

```
if ( isX(grid[i][0]) && isX(grid[i][1]) && isX(grid[i][2]))
  return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, it returns `true` because none of the grid elements has the value of zero. The `&&` operator produces `0` or `1`, depending on the values that you pass.

In the second case, it does not work as expected either: you wouldn't get an `'X'` by `&&`-ing values together.

The proper way of checking if three items are equal to `'X'` or not would be as follows:

```
if (toupper(grid[i][0]) == 'X'
&&  toupper(grid[i][1]) == 'X'
&&  toupper(grid[i][2]) == 'X') {
    return true;
}
```

To generalize the concept of "win" in TiCTacToe, write a function that returns `true` when a sequence of three items with a specific step in each direction holds a sequence of a given character, like this:

```
bool isWin(int r, int c, int dr, int dc, char ch) {
    return toupper(grid[r+0*dr][c+0*dc] == ch
        && toupper(grid[r+1*dr][c+1*dc] == ch
        && toupper(grid[r+2*dr][c+2*dc] == ch;
}
bool isWin(char ch) {
    return isWin(0,0,0,1,ch)
        || isWin(0,0,1,0,ch)
        || isWin(1,0,0,1,ch)
        || isWin(0,1,1,0,ch)
        || isWin(2,0,0,1,ch)
        || isWin(0,2,1,0,ch)
        || isWin(0,0,1,1,ch)
        || isWin(2,0,-1,1,ch);
}
```