# The incomparable types: boolean and int error

Tags: if-statement

[image]

I'm facing an error when I'm trying to do an if statement! The error is incomparable types boolean and int...

Any help would be so appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: That's not how operators work, `==` is a binary operator (therefore only two operands)

Comment: i tried this     :(d1 == d3) && (d3 == n1) && (n1== n3) ddnt work

Comment: `d1==d3 && d1==n1 && d1==n3` would be more appropriate

Comment: Can you explain. What did not work mean. I guess, when you remove the ; after your if statement it will work.

Comment: found it thanx !

Answer (score -1):

You have to check each equality individually with LOGICAL AND (&&).  For example:

```
if (d1 == d3 && d1 == n1 && d1 == n3 && d3 == n1 && d3 == n3 && n1 == N3)
    System.out.println("Too Special");
```

Another way is to use a BINARY LOGICAL AND (&):

```
int isvalid = (d1 & d3 & n1 & n3);
if (isvalid)
    System.out.println("Too Special");
```

You can also check out another answer:

[How can I check whether multiple variables are equal to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196796/how-can-i-check-whether-multiple-variables-are-equal-to-the-same-value][1])

Comment: I changed the answer.  I hope this is better. Thanks for the advice.